# System.Collections.ArrayList.ToArray method is null

Tags: vb.net, linq, expression-trees

I'm trying do get the ToArray method, but I get always null (nothing).

```
Dim toarrayMethod = GetType(System.Collections.ArrayList).GetMethod("ToArray", New Type() {GetType(Object())})
```

Searching on the net brought no solution.

**EDIT:** I would like to build this query:

```
Dim test = result.GroupBy(Function(row) groupedindexes.Select(
                              Function(grpindex) row(grpindex)).ToArray, comp)
```

With the corrected `toarrayMethod` I get the error on the image:

[image]

I know, I must change this part: `GetType(System.Collections.ArrayList)` and I was trying to change this, but then I got always the error, that the method is null.

I imagined something like this:

```
Dim toarrayMethod = GetType(System.Func(Of Object(), IEnumerable(Of Object)))...
```

Can you help me out again?

Comment: There's only one overload and the type of that parameter is `Type` not `Object()`. [ArrayList.ToArray Method (Type)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fcyyh2hb%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). GetMethod("ToArray") should be enough.

Comment: Use only GetMethod("ToArray") gives the error "Ambiguous match found.".

And if I write GetMethod("ToArray", New Type() {GetType(Type())}), the method is nothing too.

Comment: Well, then you need to pass an empty type array: `.GetMethod("ToArray", New Type(-1) {})`

Comment: BTW, you generally don't want to use `ArrayList` if you can avoid avoid it. Instead, you should use `List<T>`.

Answer (score 2):

There is no [`ArrayList.ToArray(Object)` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Collections.ArrayList.ToArray(v=vs.110).aspx), which you're requesting by `"ToArray", New Type() {GetType(Object())}`.

You're looking for `ArrayList.ToArray()` or `ArrayList.ToArray(Type)`:

```
GetMethod("ToArray")
GetMethod("ToArray", New Type() {GetType(Type())})
```